# bash builtins: jobs & wait perplexing behaviour

Tags: bash

Here's a little bash script for which I don't understand the output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 & sleep 1 & sleep 2
jobs -p
echo "====="

wait
jobs -p
```

```
22791
22792
=====
22792
```

I would expect the second `jobs -p` to not output anything but that isn't the case o_O

And if I replace the first `jobs -p` with `jobs` (without any argument), then the other  `jobs -p` doesn't output anything.

**note:** tested with bash 3.2, 4.2 and 4.4

---

###### Update

Two other examples that start with:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 & sleep 1 & sleep 2
jobs -p
echo "====="
```

1. 

```sh
# ...
jobs > /dev/null
jobs -p
```

```
23123
23124
=====
```

2. 

```sh
# ...
jobs | :
jobs -p
```

```
23131
23132
=====
23131
23132
```

Comment: If you run a similar command in an interactive shell (`sleep 1 & sleep 1 & sleep 2; jobs -p; echo "==="; wait; jobs -p`), neither call to `jobs` outputs anything, as all background jobs have completed before you run `jobs`. I wonder if `jobs` works properly in a non-interactive shell. (Enabling job monitoring with `set -m` doesn't seem to change the behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the last `sleep` into the background (missing `&`).

---

Adding `set -x` to the script gives us some usefull info:

```
+ sleep 2
+ sleep 1
+ sleep 1
+ jobs -p
1037
1038
+ echo =====
=====
+ wait
+ jobs -p
1038
```

1. The last `sleep` is called first in the foreground
2. `jobs -p` only sees 2 background pid's, both the `sleep 1`
3. `wait` is called
4. `jobs -p` shows the same sleep id as the first one, ...not sure why tho

---

Changing the line to:

```sh
sleep 1 & sleep 1 & sleep 2 &
                            ^
```

Gives the expected outcome:

```
99436
99437
99438
=====
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect either `jobs -p` to output anything in that case, since `sleep 2` prevents the first from executing until after both background jobs are done. Also, neither background job should still exist after `wait` completes. I noted in a comment the question that my expected behavior occurs in an *interactive* shell.

Comment: `sleep` is non-interruptible, so I could imagine a race condition of some kind where `jobs -p` executes before the shell notices that the previous jobs have completed, but I would still expect no output from the call after `wait`.

Comment: Yes, using `wait` when there is a running sub-process (and completed ones) makes the next call to `jobs -p` give an empty output; that is why I find it surprising that waiting for already completed sub-processes doesn't behave the same way.